# More than 6 characters string repeated

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to find the repeated strings (not words) from text.

```
x = 'This is a sample text and this is lowercase text that is repeated.'
```

In this example, the string ' text ' should not return because only 6 characters match with one another. But the string 'his is ' is the expected value returned.

I tried using range, Counter and regular expression.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

duplist = list()
for i in range(1, 30):
  mylist = re.findall('.{1,'+str(i)+'}', x)
  duplist.append([k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1])
```

Comment: So you actually look for the `single longest repeating string`, not `the reapeated strings`, is that correct?

Comment: I don't know what your regex is doing in the code below.

Comment: Whey wouldn't ```e text ``` (blank char at the end) be in the expected output?

Comment: Can the same characters be part of multiple repeating strings? For example, given input where `thisisinteresting` appears twice should `thisisi`, `thisisin`, `thisisint`, `hisisin`, etc. appear in the output? Please [edit] your question to show more than just 1 line of sample input and make sure to include all interesting cases, including overlapping repeating 7+ char strings so we can see your needs and have something to copy/paste to test with. Also state if the target strings should repeat just in 1 line or across the whole input file.

Comment: Make sure to include regexp metachars in your example to test that whatever solution is proposed doesn't, for example, consider `foo.ball` as repeat of `football`.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question about your requirements, nor an adequate sample input/output for us to suggest a robust solution - you might need just about anything and we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a quantifier of `{7,}` to ensure that a match is more than 6 characters long, and use a positive lookahead pattern with a backreference to assert that the captured string is repeated:

```
import re

x = 'This is a sample text and this is lowercase text that is repeated.'
print(re.findall(r'(.{7,})(?=.*\1)', x, re.S))
```

This outputs:

```
['his is ', 'e text ']
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/jZvQR5

Comment: This stops working on large corpus.

Comment: For `x = 'abcdefabcdef bcdefab'` this reports 'abcdef' even though that's only 6, not more than 6, and it's missing 'bcdefab', which *is* more than 6.

Comment: Is the large corpus a multi-line text? If so, you would need the `re.S` flag to allow `.` to match a newline.

Comment: @shantanuo What does "stops working" mean?

Comment: @KellyBundy Although the title says "more than 6 characters", in the body of the question the OP says "because only 6 characters match with one another", so I figured the title actually meant to say "at least 6 characters" due to the OP's presumably non-native English. Your sample input correctly produces `['bcdefab']` with my code, by the way. Demo: https://ideone.com/PCdLdj

Comment: I had a typo. Already fixed. Try the updated string. And when they say "only 6", they say that "should **not** return", i.e., matching the title.

Comment: The answer is correct. But does not scale. Kernel crashes if the text is large.

Comment: @KellyBundy Now that I reread that sentence, I agree with you that "more than 6 characters" is what's meant by the OP. Thanks. I also see your point with that sample input. One can capture the string a forward lookahead pattern to allow overlaps between matches: https://ideone.com/1FX1TF But yeah a `.*` in a lookahead is expensive in a large text.

Comment: @shantanuo If your input is very big then you need a better algorithm, like one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93673/446792)

Answer (score 1):

A better tool for the job would be to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which supports [PCRE2 extensions](https://docs.rs/pcre2/latest/pcre2/), to use along with the native regular expression support in Rust standard library.

With the regex provided from [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77534944/5291015) (original credit), ripgrep can find the matches you are looking for with

```bash
echo 'This is a sample text and this is lowercase text that is repeated.' |
   rg --pcre2 --no-unicode --case-sensitive -o -N '(.{7,})(?=.*\1)'
```

produces the result as expected.

```
his is
e text
```

Though it is a known fact that the PCRE2 extensions in ripgrep are slower than the regex library in stdlib, it should still solve the use case here. (See [Why does ripgrep get slower when I enable PCRE2 regexes?](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/FAQ.md#pcre2-slow) for a detailed write-up)

I haven't had a chance to benchmark this in detail, but on testing this on a large file ([reference link](https://norvig.com/big.txt)) containing 1095695 words (approx 1M words), `ripgrep` was able to extract 12776 matches in 170s (approx 3 min)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you want but without clearer requirements and more comprehensive sample input/output it's just one possible guess and only really tested with the one line of sample input provided:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { minStrLgth = 7 }
{
    delete cnt
    lineLgth   = length($0)
    maxStrLgth = int((lineLgth + 1)/ 2)
    endCharPos = lineLgth - minStrLgth + 1

    for ( begCharPos=1; begCharPos<=endCharPos; begCharPos++ ) {
        maxChars = (lineLgth - begCharPos) + 1
        for ( numChars=minStrLgth; numChars<=maxChars; numChars++ ) {
            str = substr($0,begCharPos,numChars)
            if ( ++cnt[str] == 2 ) {
                print str
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
his is
e text
```

I did run it on the sample input file that @Inian found at https://norvig.com/big.txt and FWIW it found 101,930 per-line matches (i.e. about 10 times the number Inian's script found due to our different guesses at the OPs requirements) in 6 minutes.

Comment: Can you match Inian's output? Not trying to reinvent, but because awk is available and ripgrep (with PCRE2 support) is difficult to install.

Comment: No because I don't know exactly what Inian's script does as I've never used `rg` nor PCREs, nor do I know what their output is. If my script does something undesirable then tell me what it is and edit your question to better state your requirements and provide sample input/output that we can test with for a simple pass/fail result.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in @Tyler's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/93673/6890912) as linked by @mx0's comment, the possibly most efficient approach to finding maximal repeated substrings would be to build a suffix array from the given string so the search can be done in linear time complexity and without the OOP overhead of a suffix tree. Although that answer mentions the difficulty in constructing a suffix array efficiently, it actually can be done in linear time complexity with the DC3/skew algorithm as detailed in the [*Simple Linear Work Suffix Array Construction*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/paralg/papers/KarkkainenSanders03.pdf) paper published by Juha Karkkainen and Peter Sanders in 2003, which someone took the time to implement in pure Python 2 as the [`pysuffix`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pysuffix/) project, with which someone else then implemented a utility class to perform maximal repeated substring search as the [`py-rstr-max`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/py-rstr-max/) project, which I have merged with `pysuffix` and converted to Python 3 as follows:

```
from array import array

class Rstr_max:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array_str = []

    def add_str(self, str_unicode):
        self.array_str.append(str_unicode)

    def step1_sort_suffix(self):
        char_frontier = chr(2)

        self.global_suffix = char_frontier.join(self.array_str)

        nbChars = len(self.global_suffix)
        init = [-1] * nbChars
        self.idxString = array('i', init)
        self.idxPos = array('i', init)
        self.endAt = array('i', init)

        k = idx = 0
        for mot in self.array_str:
            last = k + len(mot)
            for p in range(len(mot)):
                self.idxString[k] = idx
                self.idxPos[k] = p
                self.endAt[k] = last
                k += 1
            idx += 1
            k += 1

        self.res = direct_kark_sort(self.global_suffix)

    def step2_lcp(self):
        n = len(self.res)
        init = [0] * n
        rank = array('i', init)
        LCP = array('i', init)

        s = self.global_suffix
        suffix_array = self.res
        endAt = self.endAt

        for i in range(len(self.array_str), n):
            v = self.res[i]
            rank[v] = i

        l = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if (l > 0):
                l -= 1
            i = rank[j]
            j2 = suffix_array[i - 1]
            if i:
                while l + j < endAt[j] and l + j2 < endAt[j2] and s[j + l] == s[j2 + l]:
                    l += 1
                LCP[i - 1] = l
            else:
                l = 0
        self.lcp = LCP

    def step3_rstr(self):
        prev_len = 0
        idx = 0
        results = {}
        len_lcp = len(self.lcp) - 1

        class Stack:
            pass

        stack = Stack()
        stack._top = 0
        stack.lst_max = []

        if len(self.res) == 0:
            return {}

        pos1 = self.res[0]
        for idx in range(len_lcp):
            current_len = self.lcp[idx]
            pos2 = self.res[idx + 1]
            end_ = max(pos1, pos2) + current_len
            n = prev_len - current_len
            if n < 0:
                stack.lst_max.append([-n, idx, end_])
                stack._top += -n
            elif n > 0:
                self.removeMany(stack, results, n, idx)
            elif stack._top > 0 and end_ > stack.lst_max[-1][-1]:
                stack.lst_max[-1][-1] = end_

            prev_len = current_len
            pos1 = pos2

        if (stack._top > 0):
            self.removeMany(stack, results, stack._top, idx + 1)

        return results

    def removeMany(self, stack, results, m, idxEnd):
        prevStart = -1
        while m > 0:
            n, idxStart, maxEnd = stack.lst_max.pop()
            if prevStart != idxStart:
                id_ = (maxEnd, idxEnd - idxStart + 1)
                if id_ not in results or results[id_][0] < stack._top:
                    results[id_] = (stack._top, idxStart)
                prevStart = idxStart
            m -= n
            stack._top -= n
        if m < 0:
            stack.lst_max.append([-m, idxStart, maxEnd - n - m])
            stack._top -= m

    def go(self):
        self.step1_sort_suffix()
        self.step2_lcp()
        r = self.step3_rstr()
        return r

def radixpass(a, b, r, s, n, k):
    c = array("i", [0] * (k + 1))
    for i in range(n):
        c[r[a[i] + s]] += 1

    somme = 0
    for i in range(k + 1):
        freq, c[i] = c[i], somme
        somme += freq

    for i in range(n):
        b[c[r[a[i] + s]]] = a[i]
        c[r[a[i] + s]] += 1

def simple_kark_sort(s):
    alphabet = [None] + sorted(set(s))
    k = len(alphabet)
    t = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
    n = len(s)
    SA = array('i', [0] * (n + 3))
    s = array('i', [t[c] for c in s] + [0] * 3)
    kark_sort(s, SA, n, k)
    return (s, SA)

def direct_kark_sort(s):
    alphabet = [None] + sorted(set(s))
    k = len(alphabet)
    n = len(s)
    t = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(alphabet))
    SA = array('i', [0] * (n + 3))
    kark_sort(array('i', [t[c] for c in s] + [0] * 3), SA, n, k)
    return SA[:n]

def kark_sort(s, SA, n, K):
    n0 = (n + 2) // 3
    n1 = (n + 1) // 3
    n2 = n // 3
    n02 = n0 + n2

    SA12 = array('i', [0] * (n02 + 3))
    SA0 = array('i', [0] * n0)

    s12 = [i for i in range(n + (n0 - n1)) if i % 3]
    s12.extend([0] * 3)
    s12 = array('i', s12)

    radixpass(s12, SA12, s, 2, n02, K)
    radixpass(SA12, s12, s, 1, n02, K)
    radixpass(s12, SA12, s, 0, n02, K)

    name = 0
    c0, c1, c2 = -1, -1, -1
    for i in range(n02):
        if s[SA12[i]] != c0 or s[SA12[i] + 1] != c1 or s[SA12[i] + 2] != c2:
            name += 1
            c0 = s[SA12[i]]
            c1 = s[SA12[i] + 1]
            c2 = s[SA12[i] + 2]
        if SA12[i] % 3 == 1:
            s12[SA12[i] // 3] = name
        else:
            s12[SA12[i] // 3 + n0] = name

    if name < n02:
        kark_sort(s12, SA12, n02, name + 1)
        for i in range(n02):
            s12[SA12[i]] = i + 1
    else:
        for i in range(n02):
            SA12[s12[i] - 1] = i

    s0 = array('i', [SA12[i] * 3 for i in range(n02) if SA12[i] < n0])
    radixpass(s0, SA0, s, 0, n0, K)

    p = j = k = 0
    t = n0 - n1
    while k < n:
        i = SA12[t] * 3 + 1 if SA12[t] < n0 else (SA12[t] - n0) * 3 + 2
        j = SA0[p] if p < n0 else 0

        if SA12[t] < n0:
            test = (s12[SA12[t] + n0] <= s12[j // 3]) if (s[i] == s[j]) else (s[i] < s[j])
        elif (s[i] == s[j]):
            test = s12[SA12[t] - n0 + 1] <= s12[j // 3 + n0] if (s[i + 1] == s[j + 1]) else s[i + 1] < s[j + 1]
        else:
            test = s[i] < s[j]

        if (test):
            SA[k] = i
            t += 1
            if t == n02:
                k += 1
                while p < n0:
                    SA[k] = SA0[p]
                    p += 1
                    k += 1

        else:
            SA[k] = j
            p += 1
            if p == n0:
                k += 1
                while t < n02:
                    SA[k] = (SA12[t] * 3) + 1 if SA12[t] < n0 else ((SA12[t] - n0) * 3) + 2
                    t += 1
                    k += 1
        k += 1

def LCP(s, suffix_array):
    n = len(s)
    init = [0] * n
    rank = array('i', init)
    LCP = array('i', init)
    for i in range(n):
        rank[suffix_array[i]] = i
    l = 0
    for j in range(n):
        l = max(0, l - 1)
        i = rank[j]
        j2 = suffix_array[i - 1]
        if i:
            while l + j < n and l + j2 < n and s[j + l] == s[j2 + l]:
                l += 1
            LCP[i - 1] = l
        else:
            l = 0
    return LCP
```

so that:

```
x = 'This is a sample text and this is lowercase text that is repeated.'
rstr = Rstr_max()
rstr.add_str(x)
print([
    rstr.global_suffix[offset_end - length:offset_end]
    for (offset_end, _), (length, _) in rstr.go().items() if length > 6
])
```

outputs:

```
['e text ', 'his is ']
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/V7I1pd

With my ancient laptop running on Intel i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz and 8GB of RAM, the code above was able to find in the [large text file](https://norvig.com/big.txt) referenced by @Inian a total of 1,445,020 repeated substrings that are longer than 6 characters with CPython 3.11 in 72 seconds, or with [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/), in 13 seconds.

Demo on replit: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/RepeatedSubstrings